# Can't install Django 2.0 by pip

Tags: python, django

I am building new Django app with a new version of Django.
I found Django 2.0 is available (2.0.2) https://www.djangoproject.com/download/, and now trying to install it with pip.

> pip install Django==2.0.2

But it's not working for me.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0
>   (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5,
>   1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10) No matching distribution found for Django==2.0

I am using python 2.7.14 and pip 9.0.1. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`Django 2.x` is not supported using `Python 2.x`.

From the [Django download page](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/):

> We recommend using the latest version of Python 3. The last version to
>   support Python 2.7 is Django 1.11 LTS.

You should use `Python 3.x` with `Pip3`:

```
pip3 install Django
```

Answer (score 17):

if python3 is installed then try

```
pip3 install Django==2.0.2
```

Comment: Thank you! Remarkable that `pip3` is not mentioned anywhere around installing Python 3 om my Mac..

Comment: I've got py2.7 and py3 installed, thanks so much for this, was so confused!

Answer (score 1):

Django 2.0 only supports Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Same stuation is happen to me for django 2.1.2. I've tried this one below and its work fine for me.

```
pip3 install django==2.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/)

> Python compatibility Django 2.0 supports Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. We
>   highly recommend and only officially support the latest release of
>   each series. The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python
>   2.7. Django 2.0 will be the last release series to support Python 3.4. If you plan a deployment of Python 3.4 beyond the end-of-life for
>   Django 2.0 (April 2019), stick with Django 1.11 LTS (supported until
>   April 2020) instead. Note, however, that the end-of-life for Python
>   3.4 is March 2019.