# MacOS - ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==2.2.7

Tags: python, django, macos, pip

I was trying to install django in virtual env on MacOS but I'm getting this error

```
$sudo pip install django==2.2.7    
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==2.2.7

$ python -m django --version
/Users/mbp/django/django/bin/python: No module named django
```

How do I install django?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932445/cant-install-django-2-0-by-pip Django 2.x is only supported with 3.x

Comment: 2.2.7 is valid for python 3.x, not 2.x. Which are you trying to use?

Comment: Avoid using `sudo` with `pip install`. You can end up installing into the system python instead of the virtual env that you expect. Make sure you have activated the virtual env, then run `pip install django==2.2.7`.

Comment: by the way, Django 2.2.8 and 3.0 were released today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try That

```
pip3 install django==2.2.7
```

Because Django is not supported in python 2 so you need to use python 3.7 or higher

if you don't have python3 you can install it from here:

https://www.techiediaries.com/ubuntu-install-python/

Then try:

```
pip3 install django==2.2.7
```

Comment: Tx pip3 did the magic.

Comment: @GeorgeT Thanks Can You Please Also Upvote me! Thanks!